# How to get csv cell value by row and column values

Tags: php

I have a simple CSV table

```
Name,Year of birth,City
Yeremy,1980,New York
Louis,1982,Washington
Marta,1987,Chicago
David,1985,Los Angeles
```

Also, I have this code to can get cell value by number of row and number of column:

```
$trow = 3;
$tcolumn = 3;

$output .= '<span>';
$row = 1;
$mycsvfile = array();
if (($handle = fopen($abspath, "r")) !== FALSE) {
   while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
   $num = count($data);
   $row++;
   $mycsvfile[] = $data;.
   }
   fclose($handle);
}
$output .= $mycsvfile[$trowN][$tcolumnN];
$output .= '</span>';
```

I want to define that $trow=Marta and $tcolumn=City, so, in this case to get value "Chicago"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code could be optimized a lot, but with the current code:

```
$output .= array_column($mycsvfile, null, 0)['Marta'][2];
```

- Re-index the array on the values in the `Name` (column `0`)
- Access the one with index `Marta`, getting the value in the `City` (column `2`)

You can access by column name if you combine the column names:

```
if (($handle = fopen($abspath, "r")) !== FALSE) {
   $columns = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");

   while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
       $mycsvfile[] = array_combine($columns, $data);
   }
   fclose($handle);
}
$output .= array_column($mycsvfile, null, 'Name')['Marta']['City'];
```

Keep in mind that if `Marta` occurs more than once in the `Name` column then the LAST one will be returned.